# How to change user password ubuntu

Tags: fiware, ubuntu-18.04

Good Morning.
I created a machine in fiware lab cloud and I installed graphical interface.
I'm trying to change the language, but when I try, it asks me for the ubuntu user's password. When we create the machine in fiware it does not ask to inform the password, so I do not know the password of the user ubuntu. note:  can anybody help me?

Comment: Can't you just press submit without entering any password?

Comment: i tried this too, but it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem.
I changed the ubuntu user password with this command: "sudo passwd Ubuntu"
And I created a new password. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The images are thought without password. This means that they are not intended to be used with a password but using a Key Pair with SSH. For security reasons.